# custom request with join create query builder

Tags: symfony4

I have a table "note" with a "matiere_id", I have a table "matiere" with a field name.
I would like to display the average of the notes by subject.
I do not know how to write my request with symfony4.

in my repository :

```
public function findTest($id)
    {
        return $this -> createQueryBuilder ( 'n' )
            ->select("avg(n.note) as note_avg")
            ->where('n.idMatiere = :idMatiere')
            ->groupBy('n.idMatiere')
            ->setParameter('idMatiere', $id)
            ->getQuery();
    }
```

in my controlleur :

```
 $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Notation::class);
        $tabMatieres = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Matiere::class)
            ->findBy([], ['nom' => 'ASC']);

        $tests = $repo->findTest ();
```

Comment: You are not passing an `$id` to `$repo->findTest ()` and `$repo->findTest ()` is returning a query and not a result.

Comment: when I put the id in : $repo->findtest($id). I have an error message. undefined variable $id

Comment: So you need to define it.